# Don't recreate UITextField on Tap if UITextField is already created

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uitapgesturerecognizer

I've some ideas, but of course that doesn't OK for the first creation of UITextField with the "if condition".
How can I make that ?
Can I make a condition like "if UITextField already exist" ???

Here is my code :

```
-(void)tapDetected:(UIGestureRecognizer*)recognizer{
    NSLog(@"tap detected.");
    CGPoint point = [recognizer locationInView:self.truckImageView];
    UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, point.y, 300, 40)];
    [textField becomeFirstResponder];
    textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    textField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:24];
    textField.placeholder = @"enter text";
    textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
    textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
    textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
    textField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
    textField.delegate = self;
    if (textField.text && textField.text.length > 0)
    {
    [self.view addSubview:textField];
    //    textField.alpha = 0.5;
    [textField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"textField is already created.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. When creating UITextField you may assign a tag:

```
textField.tag = 1001;
```

Then before creating again you may check

```
UITextField *txt = [self.view viewWithTag:1001];
if(txt.tag == 1001)
  return;
```

Answer (score -1):

I would declare a UITextField in the header file as below

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UITextField *textField;
```

Then test for self.textField being null when in your tap function:

```
if(self.texField == NULL){
    //enter code
}
```

remember to replace all `textfield` to self.textfield in your code